# Counting bounded genus non-isomorphic graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, bipartite-graphs, isomorphism-testing

What is the number of non-isomorphic $2n$ vertex balanced bipartite graphs of degree at most $d$ and genus $g$?

I am most interested in $d\leq3$ and $g=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Closely related questions are considered in [

*Guillaume Chapuy, Éric Fusy, Omer Giménez, Bojan Mohar, and Marc Noy*, MR 2745423 [**Asymptotic enumeration and limit laws for graphs of fixed genus**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2010.11.014), *J. Combin. Theory Ser. A* **118** (2011), no. 3, 748--777.][1](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~fusy/Articles/GraphsHigherGenus.pdf)